# Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 41 - sys.argv

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I am programmer newbie and I'm working my way through the exercises. In Exercise 41 I'm little bit confused (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex41.html).

I don't understand line n. 25:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
```

I have tried looking up what sys.argv does but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. From what I could understand - sys.argv is a list of command line arguments, however I don't understand where those arguments in the script are located. Thus I don't understand the branching.

I understand that "len" counts the number of items in that list which means there have to be at least three arguments and first item in the list must contain string "english". I just don't understand how the arguments are declared in this specific script.

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: There must me *exactly **two*** arguments.

Comment: I know that if I run the script with "english" argument I get reverse function, However the argument is not defined in the script. Or do I just assign it in the IF branching?

Comment: The **next** line is only executed when the `if` condition is `True`. It sets a boolean flag, and the rest of the code alters behaviour based on that flag. `sys.argv` is set by Python when the interpreter starts and sees what arguments were used on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the other thread. It explained a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those arguments *aren't* located in the script. They are called command line arguments because they are provided by the user when calling a script from the command line:

```
python oop_test.py english
                 # ^ sys.argv[1]
     # ^ sys.argv[0]
```

So the code you have first checks that there are exactly two arguments provided (not "at least three"), then that the second (Python is zero-based, so the first item would be `argv[0]`) is `"english"`.

The first item in `argv` is always the script name; [see the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: Oh I see now... I finally understand it. But still if there is
> if len(sys.argv) == 2
it has to be three items right? because sys.argv[0] is script name, sys.argv[1] is "english"

but at least now I know this list is created before running the script, in command line. thats why I was confused...

Comment: No, although the indices are zero-based (`0` and `1`), `len`  returns the number of items (which is one larger the largest index) *not* the largest index.

Comment: Damn Im pretty sure Ive read the documentation, I must be exhausted from all that reading of course LEN works that way. Thank you for reminding me that.
Now I need to figure out the rest of the script.